# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main PID: 7700

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

`enter code here`while I test my app, I get the follow error in the Android-Studio-Consol:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper, PID: 7700
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper/com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TableLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6633)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TableLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TableLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TableLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper-fPrKTt4RFBuXWYEc0AM1Zg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper-fPrKTt4RFBuXWYEc0AM1Zg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:610)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:999)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:999)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7084)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7075)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2765)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6633)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Splash Screen

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();

        }
    },3000); // Sleep 3 seconds
}
```

}

HomeActivity.java

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

```
   package com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper;
```

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("EDMT Wallpaper");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    MyFragmentAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Adapter code

MyFragmentAdapter.java

package com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper.Adapter;

public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
private Context context;

public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return CategoryFragment.getInstance();
    else if (position == 1)
        return DailyPopularFragment.getInstance();
    else if (position == 2)
        return RecentsFragment.getInstance();
    else return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

// Ctrl+O


@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Category";
        case 1:
            return "Daily Popular";
        case 2:
            return "Recents";
    }

    return "";

}
```

}

Fragment code

CategoryFragment.java

package com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper.Fragment;

public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static CategoryFragment INSTANCE=null;

public CategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static CategoryFragment getInstance(){
    if (INSTANCE == null)
        INSTANCE = new CategoryFragment();
    return INSTANCE;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
}
```

}

DailyPopularFragment.java

package com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper.Fragment;

public class DailyPopularFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static DailyPopularFragment INSTANCE=null;
public DailyPopularFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static DailyPopularFragment getInstance(){
    if (INSTANCE == null)
        INSTANCE = new DailyPopularFragment();
    return INSTANCE;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily_popular, container, false);
}
```

}

RecentsFragment.java

package com.example.buratinoapps.wallpaper.Fragment;

public class RecentsFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static RecentsFragment INSTANCE=null;
public RecentsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static RecentsFragment getInstance(){
    if (INSTANCE == null)
        INSTANCE = new RecentsFragment();
    return INSTANCE;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recents, container, false);
}
```

}

Comment: The XML and build.gradle are what we need.

Comment: Can you please post the minimal piece of code to reproduce your error? Also, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You apparently have a typo in the `activity_home` layout. `android.support.design.widget.TableLayout` should be `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` – `TabLayout`, instead of `TableLayout`. There is no `TableLayout` in the design library.

Comment: and there is android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Comment: Yep, there is: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout. Did that fix it?

Comment: I connected to android.support.design.widget.TabLayout initiallyimport android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

Comment: No, the problem is in the layout XML, in `activity_home.xml`. You have a `<android.support.design.widget.TableLayout>` element there. It should be `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>`.

Answer (score 0):

The hint is in the following line in your logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TableLayout"
```

make sure you include  the design library in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

if your target sdk is other than 28, use the appropriate library number to match your app's sdk.

Comment: As Mike M suggested above, try correcting the TableLayout to TabLayout. Good catch! I hadn't noticed that myself

Comment: implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'